# MySQL Convert 48 Hours into 48:00:00

Tags: mysql, date

I have a regular **DATETIME** row, eg: **2012-06-19 13:56:56**

I am running the following to see how much the time difference is:

```
DATEDIFF(end_time, NOW()) * 24
```

It returns **48**

Edit: How do I get the Minutes/Seconds? I have tried `UNIXTIME(field) - UNIXTIME(NOW())` but i cant get beyond it.

Im trying to convert this into **48:00:00** (Or however that timestamp works)

I keep looking up time functions but they have to do with EXTRACT, and Im not sure thats the way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since datediff only ever returns a difference in days, you might as well just use a string operation to do your formating:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEDIFF(end_time, NOW()) * 24), ':00:00')
```

Comment: But I don't think will work if the time difference is in minutes or seconds, which id like to keep..

Comment: then don't use datediff, since it ONLY returns differences as days. hint: **DATE** diff, not **TIME** diff.